# How to always launch MainActivity or HomeActivity when user open deep linked activity and press back button

Tags: android, android-activity, deep-linking

**How to open MainActivity on BackPressed or back button was pressed when deep linked activity was opened**

Let's us suppose we have activity

*www.xyz.com/abc* - **Deep linked URL**

When user click on this url ABCActivity was opened, but on back pressed the app was closed how to open HomeActivity or MainActivity

Comment: you can override the onBackPressed() function

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch first The MainActivity & after that, you have the data from where you can check to which Activity you want to open

> String activity=referrer.getString("TAG");

pass the intent from MainActivity to activity you want to open, now in stack two activities are there, after pressing back Main Activity will open.

Comment: is it possible to achieve this thing by some intent flag

Answer (score 0):

you need check start normal or deep link and in onBackPress use this

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //...
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                isStartFromDeepLink = extras.getBoolean("isStartFromDeepLink", false);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(isStartFromDeepLink){
           startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
        }else{
           finish()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve the problem using this code

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity"/>
```